# how to display the results of a radio button on a contact form in an email

Tags: php

I am an old mainframe programmer but website novice, I use Dreamweaver to amend my website but am only self taught, so I muddle through.  I have a simple contact form on my website and have added a couple of radio buttons.  I have been trying for hours to display the results of the radio buttons on the contact email but cant work it out.  This is part of the form:-

```
    <td align="left"><span class="style5">Contact No</span></td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" name="number" style="width:300px;"  />
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td valign="top" align="left"><span class="style5">Question</span></td>
    <td>
      <textarea name="question" rows="8" cols="30" style="width:300px;" ></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Contact By </td>
    <td align="center">
        <label for="radiobutton">email</label>
        <input name="radiobutton" type="radio" value="radiobutton" id="radiobutton">
        <label for="checkbox">phone</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="checkbox" id="checkbox">
</tr>
```

This is the email, what do I add to display the radio button result please, I have tried about a hundred different things and nothing works!

```
$nl = "\n\n"; 
if($_POST[sendmail]==1)
{
    $message .= "Email Address: $_POST[email] ".$nl;
    $message .= "First Name: $_POST[first]".$nl;
    $message .= "Last Name: $_POST[last]".$nl;
    $message .= "Country: $_POST[country]".$nl;     
    $message .= "Contact No: $_POST[number]".$nl;       
    $message .= "Question: $_POST[question]".$nl;



    $message .= "IP: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'].$nl; 
    $message .= "Host: ".gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).$nl;
```

Comment: I don't see a POST array for the radio button.

Comment: *"This is the email, what do I add to display the radio button result please"* - A: add it as you did for the other POST arrays.

Comment: A Radio Button SET is normally used for 2 or more options to be presented where only one can be selected!

Comment: You are also missing a closing `</td>` in that Contact By row of the  table!

Comment: It might also be usful to know where (or IF) your `<form....>` tag exists and the attributes you set within it

Comment: I fear this question is just going to sit here and get ignored unless you provide us with a bit more of the code

Comment: I haven't added the POST for the radio button as everything I have tried has failed to work! I  have been searching the internet for answers and have got so confused with the many different options.  Bear in mind I am not experienced I muddle my way through so don't ask too many technical questions

Answer (score 0):

you may want to change your HTML to something like this so that when you access the variables it's more readable:

```
   <label for="contactByEmail">Email</label>
   <input type="radio" name="contactByEmail"  id="contactByEmail" value="1">
```

If the email button is selected, the value of contactByEmail will be 1. So to display the radio button result you can do something like:

```
if($_POST[contactByEmail]==1)
{
    $message .= "Contact By: Email".$nl;
}
```

Hope this helps!